# send multiple objects via ajax (using angular)

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, angularjs, ajax

I have a list of user inputs in an object 'data'. (for e.g data.username, data.password, data.age)

i am passing the data object to backend like this using angular.

```
var submits = "=" + JSON.stringify(data);

$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: serviceURL,
            data: submits
});
```

I am passing two more objects. selections and grid. how can i pass all these three together in one ajax call ? or do i have to transfer it independently. will it affect the performance if i transfer these details separately.

can i do something like this to send the object together in one ajax call?

```
var data = {};
data[0] = data1;
data[1] = data2;
```

How can i retrieve it separately at the server side using c# if at all they are passed together.

Heres the 3 objects that i need to pass

```
data -->>         ["Raul","New York","31"]
selections-->>    ["dy.txt","my.txt","yy.txt"]
grid-->           ["sesion","id"]
```

Comment: What server-side technology are you using? WebAPI? MVC?

Comment: @Jasen- using mvc at the server side.

Comment: `$.ajax` is not angular but a helper method in jQuery library. You should **not** be mixing jQuery inside your angular controllers. Use the `$http` service to make web api calls from your angular code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send multiple objects / variables in ajax with:

```
var submits = "=" + JSON.stringify(data);
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: serviceURL,
        data: {submits : submits, data1:data1, data2:data2}
});
```

In your C# you can access data1 and 2 in the same way as you handle submits now.
Depending of what is in data1 and data2 you might need to stringify it first.

**second option**:
You can also if you want to (but it is more ugly) use the stringify on everything at once and only pass the string:

```
data = {};
data["data1"] = data1;
data["data2"] = data2;
var submits = "=" + JSON.stringify(data);
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you have a view model like this in your server side

```
public class CreateUserViewModel
{
  public string UserName{set;get;}
  public string Location {set;get;}
  public int Age {set;get;}
}
public class RegisterViewModel
{
  public CreateUserViewModel User {set;get;}
  public List<string> Selections {set;get;}
  public List<string> Grid {set;get;}
}
```

and an MVC action method like this

```
public ActionResult Create(RegisterViewModel model)
{
  // read model and save and return some JSON response
}
```

You can simply build the javascript object which matches the structure of the view model and post it using angualr's `$http` service. No need to worrry about setting content-Type or Json stringifying it. Angualr will take care of it.

```
var model={ User : {} ,Selections :[], Grid=[] };
model.User.Age =23;
model.User.UserName ="test";
model.User.Location="New York";

model.Selections.push("dy.txt");
model.Selections.push("some.txt");

model.Grid.push("session");
model.Grid.push("id");

var url="replcaeUrltoYourActionMethodHere";

$http.post(url, model)
.then(function(response)
{
  // do something with the response
  // var result= response.data
});
```

Comment: @Shyju- updated my question with the list of objects which will be passed and wat kind of information each will have. will the code you mentioned change now according to the updated question?

Comment: @Ayesha I updated my answer to reflect the data structure you provided.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using WebApi or MVC on the server? If so, the simplest approach would be to create a class which holds the 3 entities you need to send and leverage the built-in [model-binding](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api)

So in your example you list what looks to be a user form, selections and grids. I'm not really sure what the last two are but an example Model might look something like this:

```
public class UserSubmissionViewModel
{
    public UserSubmissionViewModel() { }

    public UserFormModel User {get;set;}

    public SelectionsModel Selections { get; set; }

    public GridModel Grids { get; set; }
}
```

Then on your web api controller or your MVC controller you'd have a method such as this:

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Submit(UserSubmissionViewModel model)
```

And your javascript would resemble something roughly like this:

```
var toSend = {"UserFormModel":data, "SelectionsModel":selections, "GridModel":grids};
$.ajax({
         type:"POST",
         data:toSend, //<--- you might need to JSON.stringify this, cant test this code at the moment
         url:serviceURL //<-- Calls your Submit method on the controller
    });
```

Comment: @b0redom- i will try using this part of the code you mentioned above

Comment: @bOredom- updated my question with the list of objects which will be passed and wat kind of information each will have. will the code you mentioned change now ?

Comment: The intent of the code will not. You will obviously need to fix the field names to match. It looks like selections is just a list, so you could just use a `string[]` instead of an actual object if you wanted.